# Regular expression help - appending an argument in a function

Tags: regex, append

I am new to regular expressions. I am looking for something that can help me do a find and replace throughout our entire code tree with any function that creates a file descriptor.

For example, I need to change `socket(PF_LOCAL,SOCK_STREAM, 0)` to `socket(PF_LOCAL,SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0)`

In each case I am appending to the end of the second argument, but I do not know how long the current second argument is going to be or what text it will contain. I am thinking the best way to do it is to find the second comma and replace that with my string (`" | SOCK_CLOEXEC,"`)

If someone could give me and example of this it would be extremely helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you're looking for but in perl:

```
s/socket\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)\)/socket($1,$2 | SOCK_CLOEXEC,$3)/
```

Which means:

`s/to_substitute/substitution_string/` "Find pattern `to_substitute` and replace it with `substitution_string`"

And I used:

`[^,]+` which means "string without comma".

`()` which are used to capture strings which are copied in substitution string with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 -- and welcome to StackOverflow -- but FYI, it's considered bad practice to write (e.g.) `\1` in the replacement-string in Perl: `$1` is recommended instead.